# How to overwrite a tag's style for just a section on the page?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I'm working on a project which was developed by previous developer. The UI looks pretty good. However, all textbox, label, etc. are big (in a good way, and we do not want to change it).

Now, we want to add a kendo grid. It turns out that because of the existing css, the grid too big, but if we reduce grid size, it only shows 2 or 3 rows. See screen shot.

It is mainly because in the css, there is a line:

```
input {height:50px!important;}
```

And obviously affects the kendo grid's look. Is there a way to remove this JUST for the grid?

Or, this is impossible unless move the grid to another page?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out. Just add this to the page:

```
<style>
    #grid input {    
        height: 10px!important;
    }
</style>
```

it works! Any better answer?